# How do I confirm if a php shell_exec was completed

Tags: php, ffmpeg, cron

I am running a php script using the cPanel Cron Jobs. The script is using `shell_exec` to convert a video using ffmpeg. It executes the script and everything is working but it is not sending me the email. I am basically trying to get the output of the `shell_exec` to start another function in the php script so I wanted to send my self the email to make sure I am getting the output.

For example I wrote:

```
$command = "ffmpeg -i $og_video -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -vpre slow -vpre baseline -g 30 $mp4_video";

//EXECUTE THE CONVERSION
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
```

I also tested the email by removing the `shell_exec` and just echo the `$command` variable. This will send me the full string in an email.

What I am trying to accomplish is basically if the shell_exec executed then do something else.

How do I check if the shell_exec was completed?

Comment: don't use shell_exec(), then. use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), which gives you output AND the exit value of the executed program.

Comment: Use a database/logging system or sth like http://gearman.org/

Comment: How long it takes to exec the script ?

Comment: When it completes it will execute the next line.

Comment: @midan888 depends on the file size.

Comment: @AbraCadaver will it execute the next line if it errors or will it stop?

Comment: Why was the answer removed? The answer to the linked post worked for me. I was able to echo the results of the `exec` command and it emailed me the results so based on the answer in the other question this will work for me.

Comment: @iamthestreets if the script takes too long it might be killed on half way, depends on configuration, check this function, maybe its because of that, http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: you can use `nohup` and execute the command in background and check `PID` for completing the command.